# How are variables bound to the body of a define_method?

Tags: ruby, reflection, metaprogramming

While trying to brush up my Ruby skills I keep running across this case which I can't figure out an explanation for by just reading the API docs. An explanation would be greatly appreciated. Here's the example code:

```
for name in [ :new, :create, :destroy ]
  define_method("test_#{name}") do
    puts name
  end
end
```

What I want/expect to happen is that the `name` variable will be bound to the block given to `define_method` and that when `#test_new` is called it will output "new". Instead each defined method outputs "destroy" -- the last value assigned to the name variable. What am I misunderstanding about `define_method` and its blocks? Thanks!

Comment: Now I'm thinking that I should expect define_method to work just like the keyword def, in which case the block given to define_method can only work with variables local to it or passed as arguments.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Blocks in Ruby are closures: the block you pass to `define_method` captures the variable `name` itself–not its value—so that it remains in scope whenever that block is called. That's the first piece of the puzzle.

The second piece is that the method defined by `define_method` *is* the block itself. Basically, it converts a `Proc` object (the block passed to it) into a `Method` object, and binds it to the receiver.

So what you end up with is a *method* that has captured (is closed over) the variable `name`, which by the time your loop completes is set to `:destroy`.

**Addition:** The `for ... in` construction actually creates a new local variable, which the corresponding `[ ... ].each {|name| ... }` construction would *not* do. That is, your `for ... in` loop is equivalent to the following (in Ruby 1.8 anyway):

```
name = nil
[ :new, :create, :destroy ].each do |name|
  define_method("test_#{name}") do
    puts name
  end
end
name # => :destroy
```

Comment: I think I get it now. It looks like you found the source of the confusion, although without explicitly naming it: the problem is not so much that the block passed to `define_method` is a closure (in fact, that is *precisely* what the OP wants), but rather that the body of a `for` expression is *not* a closure. A `for` expression creates a new *local* variable *within* the scope the `for` expression is defined in. The `each` iterator OTOH takes a block, which is of course a closure, which means that now `name` refers to the specific instance of the `name` block variable *for that one iteration*

Comment: Oh, true. And actually, the variable created by the `for ... in` expression is still in scope *after* the loop, not just in the body of the loop (as I'm testing it in `irb`).

Answer (score 1):

```
for name in [ :new, :create, :destroy ]
  local_name = name
  define_method("test_#{local_name}") do
    puts local_name
  end
end
```

This method will behave as you expect. The reason for the confusion is that 'name' is not created once per iteration of the for loop. It is created once, and incremented. In addition, if I understand correctly, method definitions are not closures like other blocks. They retain variable visibility, but do not close over the current value of the variables.

Comment: An in-depth look at the same problem (and solution) in C#: http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that `for` loop expressions do not create a new scope. The only things that create new scopes in Ruby are script bodies, module bodies, class bodies, method bodies and blocks.

If you actually look up the behavior of `for` loop expressions in the Draft ISO Ruby Specification, you will find that a `for` loop expression gets executed exactly like an `each` iterator *except* for the fact that it does not create a new scope.

No Rubyist would ever use a `for` loop, anyway: they would use an iterator instead, which *does* take a block and thus creates a new scope.

If you use an idiomatic iterator, everything works as expected:

```
class Object
  %w[new create destroy].each do |name|
    define_method "test_#{name}" do
      puts name
    end
  end
end

require 'test/unit'
require 'stringio'
class TestDynamicMethods < Test::Unit::TestCase
  def setup; @old_stdout, $> = $>, (@fake_logdest = StringIO.new) end
  def teardown; $> = @old_stdout end

  def test_that_the_test_create_method_prints_create
    Object.new.test_create
    assert_equal "create\n", @fake_logdest.string
  end
  def test_that_the_test_destroy_method_prints_destroy
    Object.new.test_destroy
    assert_equal "destroy\n", @fake_logdest.string
  end
  def test_that_the_test_new_method_prints_new
    Object.new.test_new
    assert_equal "new\n", @fake_logdest.string
  end
end
```

Comment: "No Rubyist would ever...." is a baseless assertion. Many of us find for loops much more semantic and concise than "each" blocks.