# Using local variables in define_method

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

I would like to understand how `define_method` works and how to properly use the variables outside of the definition block. Here is my code:

```
class Test
  def self.plugin
    for i in 1..2
      define_method("test#{i}".to_sym) do
        p i
      end
    end
  end
  plugin
end

ob = Test.new
ob.test1 #=> 2  (I would expect 1)
ob.test2 #=> 2  (I would expect 2)
```

It seems that in the methods `test1` and `test2`, the value of `i` is not substituted during the definition, but is computed directly on the spot when the method is called. So we see only the latest value of `i`, which is `2`. But where does Ruby take this value from? And is there a way to let `test#{i}` print `i`?

In this particular case, I could do a [workaround using `__method__`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199527/get-the-name-of-the-currently-executing-method), but probably there is a better solution.

Comment: power of _closure_ is expressed here.......... :)

Comment: Thanks for the link, the question addresses the same problem. But I am not sure the solution is provided there. At least one of the comments does not work: 
<pre><code>class Test
  for name in [ :new, :create, :destroy ]
    local_name = name
    define_method("test_#{local_name}") do
      puts local_name
    end
  end
end

ob = Test.new
ob.test_new #=> destroy  (I would expect 'new')
ob.test_create #=> destroy  (I would expect 'new')
</code></pre>

Comment: Well.. Unmarked. But here is a [similar post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2029524/how-are-variables-bound-to-the-body-of-a-define-method).

Comment: I've taken the code (sorry for markup) exactly from the [similar post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2029524/how-are-variables-bound-to-the-body-of-a-define-method) you mentioned. Just wanted to point out that the solution is proposed only in the second comment there and it does not work:-)

Comment: I cannot parse the part "... the value `i` of is not ...".

Comment: @sawa fixed, is it ok now?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As mentionned in comments this is down to closures - the block passed to `define_method` captures the local variables from its scope (and not just their value as you found out).

`for` doesn't create a new scope, so your method 'sees' the change to `i`. If you use a block (for example with each) then a new scope is created and this won't happen. You just need to change your code to

```
class Test
  def self.plugin
    (1..2).each do |i|
      define_method("test#{i}".to_sym) do
        p i
      end
    end
  end
  plugin
end
```

which is basically what the question  linked by Arup was about